# What is the latest JGroups version that can be used with Java 5?

Tags: java, java-5, jgroups

I have to use Java 5 in the my client's environment. And I have problems finding a JGroups version that still runs on Java5. I have found that 2.6.15.GA compiles and runs on Java 5, but it is quite old. 2.12.2.Final does not even compile on Java5 due to usage of new API. But there are several versions in between. Does any of you know since what time JGroups switched to Java 6?

Comment: JGroups 2.5 requires JDK 1.5 or higher. Version 2.9 requires JDK 1.6 or higher. http://www.jgroups.org/manual/html_single/index.html#d0e244

Comment: Thanks. Put it as an answer. 2.8.1.GA works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reposting @eee comment, because its valid answer:

> JGroups 2.5 requires JDK 1.5 or higher. Version 2.9 requires JDK 1.6
>   or higher. [jgroups.org/manual/html_single/index.html#d0e244](http://jgroups.org/manual/html_single/index.html#d0e244)

Answer (score 1):

I've downloaded JGroups 2.8.1 GA uploaded 2010-04-30 and it contained class-files compiled with Java 6 (50.0). Not sure how come Andrey was able to use that version?
So the latest version I could find was JGroups 2.8.0 GA uploaded 2009-12-21.
Hope this help someone that, like me, is stuck with an old environment running Java 5.